# SEM with zero-inflated indicators

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, measurement, zero-inflation, lavaan

I am using SEM and my measurement model includes around 15 items that are all rated on a 0-10 scale but highly skewed towards zero. I am wondering whether there is a way to estimate the measurement model with poisson corrections for zero inflation in R? Or would you assume that it should be sufficient to just run a generalised structural equation model that relaxes the normality assumption?

Comment: Have you asked on `lavaan` mailing list?

Comment: Please report back if Yves give you an answer, so that it is available for other people with similar issues.

Comment: Some first response I got: You might need the WLSMV estimator available in 'lavaan'. Please see:

http://www.statmodel.com/discussion/messages/9/9587.html?1423546955
http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/est.html

Comment: Na-ah, that's a poor knee-jerk reaction to anything non-normal (and that's an Mplus jargon, anyway -- like saying "data formats" a la SAS when you mean "value labels"). You really need a zip or at least a negative binomial GLM link. I am not a heavy user of `lavaan`, so I can't say if that is supported; Stata however does provide the negative binomial link with `gsem`.

Comment: Would you say binomial is more appropriate than poisson? gsem doesn't allow me to account for zero inflation though.

Comment: http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/61889/ This looks helpful but doesn't seem to exist for R yet?

Comment: To those coming to this late in the game (as I did), you might want to consider a bayesian approach in R that handles zero inflated models for mediation. This has a lot of links and tips; https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/mediation-question-using-brms/4260